# MySql Table Self Join

Tags: mysql, self-join

I have the table below

```
sku|date      |price
---|----------|-----
A1 |2015-01-10|3
A2 |2015-01-15|2
A1 |2015-01-20|5
A1 |2015-02-10|2
A2 |2015-02-10|1
```

I'm trying to get the count per month. I'd like to get the output below;

```
sku|JAN_ORDER|FEB_ORDER|JAN_TOTAL
---|---------|---------|---------
A1 |2        |1        |10
A2 |1        |1        |2
```

I've tried self join and left join with no success, and I'm getting a bit confused.

I get incorrect results with the code below

```
select s.sku, count(f.sku)
from database f, database s
where f.sku between '2015-01-01' and '2015-01-31'
and
s.sku=f.sku
group by s.sku
```

Please advise.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Like Marc B said, no need for joins :

[SQL Fiddle](http://sqlfiddle.com/#!9/aa99c/3)

**MySQL 5.6 Schema Setup**:

```
CREATE TABLE `database`
    (`sku` varchar(2), `date` datetime)
;

INSERT INTO `database`
    (`sku`, `date`)
VALUES
    ('A1', '2015-01-10 00:00:00'),
    ('A2', '2015-01-15 00:00:00'),
    ('A1', '2015-01-20 00:00:00'),
    ('A1', '2015-02-10 00:00:00'),
    ('A2', '2015-02-10 00:00:00')
;
```

**Query 1**:

```
SELECT sku,
   count(IF(month(date) = 1, sku, null)) AS JAN,
   count(IF(month(date) = 2, sku, null)) AS Feb
FROM `database`
GROUP BY sku
```

**[Results](http://sqlfiddle.com/#!9/aa99c/3/0)**:

```
| sku | JAN | Feb |
|-----|-----|-----|
|  A1 |   2 |   1 |
|  A2 |   1 |   1 |
```

Answer (score 0):

No need for joins

```
SELECT s.sku,
   SUM(IF(date = 'Jan', 1, 0)) AS JAN,
   SUM(IF(date = 'Feb', 1, 0)) AS Feb
FROM yourtable
GROUP BY sku
```

Of course, performance is going to be crappy, but since there's only 12 months, won't be terribly crappy. These sorts of transforms are invariably better done in client-side code, and just have a normal

```
SELECT sku, COUNT(date)
FROM yourtable
GROUP BY date
```